# Setting a variable and utilizing sed

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for over an hour now and my searches haven't helped yield the answer.

Trying to set a variable inside a bash script. This variable is taking variable-A and removing variable-B from it.

```
Prefix="$(echo ${Process} | sed -e 's/${Server}//g')"
```

So if `Process=abcd1wxyz01` and `Server=wxyz01`, then `Prefix` should end up being `abcd1`.

I've tried so many iterations from online searches I honestly can't recall what all I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use **`"`** instead of **`'`** while using bash variables inside `sed`:

```
Prefix="$(echo ${Process} | sed -e "s/${Server}//g")"
echo $Prefix
```

Comment: `echo "${Process}"` or `echo "$Process"` would also be more correct than `echo ${Process}`; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo). Similarly, `echo $Prefix` should be `echo "$Prefix"`

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

Your problem are the quotes, as pointed out in [afsal_p's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51991721/3266847).

You could do this with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) instead:

```
$ process=abcd1wxyz01
$ server=wxyz01
$ prefix=${process%"$server"}
$ echo "$prefix"
abcd1
```

The `${word%suffix}` expansion removes *`suffix`* from the end of *`word`*.